# In AS3, how to check if two JSON objects are equal?

Tags: json, actionscript-3

Title pretty much says it. I have two JSON objects and I want to know if they are equal (have all the same property values).

I could stringify them both, but I'm not sure if two equal objects will always produce the same output:

E.g:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "favoriteColors": ["blue", "green", "red"]
}
```

Is a different string from:

```
{
    "age": 25,
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "firstName": "John",
    "favoriteColors": ["blue", "green", "red"]
}
```

But as objects they have identical properties.

Comment: Can't you just check each of the properties against each other one at a time? `if age = age, if firstName = firstName, etc.`

Comment: I'm looking for a generalized solution that will work for any JSON object. Also, favoriteColors is an array, so simple equality comparison won't work.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my JSON, but can you loop through the properties of the first object, then for each one check the properties of the second object until the matching property is found. Once you have the two matching properties check that their values are the same. Keep looping until all properties have been checked. This can work for the arrays too, just check if it's an array, then enter another loop for array items.

Answer (score 8):

There is a method for this in the Flex SDK. It is in the class `ObjectUtil`. Here is the description from the source :

```
/**
     * Compares the Objects and returns an integer value 
     * indicating if the first item is less than greater than or equal to
     * the second item.
     * This method will recursively compare properties on nested objects and
     * will return as soon as a non-zero result is found.
     * By default this method will recurse to the deepest level of any property.
     * To change the depth for comparison specify a non-negative value for
     * the depth parameter.
     * @param   a   Object.
     * @param   b   Object.
     * @param   depth   Indicates how many levels should be 
     *   recursed when performing the comparison.
     *   Set this value to 0 for a shallow comparison of only the primitive 
     *   representation of each property.
     *   For example:
     *   var a:Object = {name:"Bob", info:[1,2,3]};
     *   var b:Object = {name:"Alice", info:[5,6,7]};
     *   var c:int = ObjectUtil.compare(a, b, 0);In the above example the complex properties of a and 
     *   b will be flattened by a call to toString()
     *   when doing the comparison.
     *   In this case the info property will be turned into a string
     *   when performing the comparison.
     * @return  Return 0 if a and b are null, NaN, or equal. 
     *   Return 1 if a is null or greater than b. 
     *   Return -1 if b is null or greater than a.
     * @langversion 3.0
     * @playerversion   Flash 9
     * @playerversion   AIR 1.1
     * @productversion  Flex 3
     */
    public static function compare (a:Object, b:Object, depth:int=-1) : int;
```

If you don't want the whole SDK maybe you can just get this function/class and use that source.

You can see the source [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.as). Most of the work is done in the function `internalCompare`.

Comment: Strange that method doesn't seem to appear in Adobe's online docs. I'm also a little confused by its intended purpose-- it seems to be designed for sorting, but the sort order would be difficult to predict for objects with multiple properties.

Comment: That function is for comparing 2 objects, it can be used for sorting by passing it to sort as a compare function. Not sure why it doesn't show on Adobe's doc could be because it is part of Flex. But you can just use the class without using the whole SDK or making a Flex App.

Comment: @justkevin The filters on the adobe docs page are probably not set to show the sdk docs

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: Barış' answer is the best option, as it's tried and tested. Just in case this comes in handy for someone though:*

Given that JSON values are limited to a small set of simple types, it should be possible to recurse through the properties fairly easily. Something along these lines works with your example:

```
private function areEqual(a:Object, b:Object):Boolean {
    if (a === null || a is Number || a is Boolean || a is String) {
        // Compare primitive values.
        return a === b;
    } else {
        var p:*;
        for (p in a) {
            // Check if a and b have different values for p.
            if (!areEqual(a[p], b[p])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        for (p in b) {
            // Check if b has a value which a does not.
            if (!a[p]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can convert the two objects to string then compare them

```
function compareJSON(a:Object, b:Object):Boolean
{
  return JSON.stringify(a)===JSON.stringify(b);
}
```

Comment: This won't work because properties don't get sorted when stringify'd.